# can't connect myxins to quasar, globally

Tags: vue.js, sass, quasar-framework

Encountered an 'Undefined mixin' error when trying to use mixin in a Quasar project running in a Docker container

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVv4f.jpg)
comments on the screen

1. here is the mixin itself
2. connected it in the quasar config as well as app.scss
3. they are in the same place

project on docker-compose quasar in a separate container, unlikely my problem is related to this but maybe. The problem itself is like this, I connect myxin for mobile layout, I want to use it throughout the project. but it gives an error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] Undefined mixin.
   ╷
18 │ ┌ @include mobile {
19 │ │ │ flex-direction: column;
20 │ └ }
   ╵
  src/components/base/CustomFooter.vue 18:7 root stylesheet
/app/src/components/base/CustomFooter.vue:52:6
```

screenshot of the error in the second photo
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7KBv.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QPYn.png)
This is how I'm trying to use myxin. Of course, if I uncomment line 36 everything will work, but I want to understand how to work globally so that I don't have to import myxin in every component.

I have already searched for solutions related to global mixin import in Quasar, but did not find a suitable one. now everything is done as it is written in the official documentation

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Sorry didn't saw you already know you can import the mixins. I didn't noticed you posted two screenshots. Unfortunately I can't help you with global including mixins and I doubt this is a quasar topic in general. You should look for vite or vue. Maybe this is some help for you:
[globally load sass into vue](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/)

---

you could add an import for the mixin in the .vue file. For example:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import 'src/css/mixins'

@include my-awesome-mixin {
  // ...
}
</style>
```